# Error with dictionary method "get" : name 'get' is not identified

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code:

```
fil = input('Enter a file name: ')
fh = open(fil)
d = dict()
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('From'):
         #print(line)
         sline = line.split()
         if len(sline) > 2:
             #print(sline)
             hours = sline[5].split(':')
             print(hours)
             for num in hours:
                 print ("the num is: ", num)
                 print('dictionary is', d)
                 d[1] = get.d(1,0) + 1
                 print (d)
                 d[num] = get.d(num,0) + 1
```

I got the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aless\Desktop\py4e\ex_10.2.py", line 15, in <module>
    d[1] = get.d(1,0) + 1
NameError: name 'get' is not defined
```

But I cannot figure out what is the problem. Unfortunately I have just started coding. Any ideas?
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I think it should be d.get(1,0).

Comment: Not only does the traceback list the line that caused the error, it tells you the _part_ of the line that is erroneous.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling get wrong.

`get` is a method on the dictionary, so what you need is:

```
d[1] = d.get(1,0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

get is a method of dictionary. As such, you should write it the other way around, i.e. `d.get(...)`.